# Lebesgue measure of boundary

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, lebesgue-measure, curves

How can we prove that if $\phi:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ function with the property that $\phi^{-1}(0)\neq \emptyset$ and $\nabla\phi(x)\neq 0,\ \forall\ x\in \phi^{-1}(0)$ then the set $\phi^{-1}(0)$ has Lebesgue Measure $0$, i.e.:

$$\mathcal{L}^N(\phi^{-1}(0))=0$$

**Remarks**

If $\phi^{-1}(0)$ contains an interior point then we have a ball $B$ on which $\phi(x)=0,\ \forall\ x\in B$. But this means that $\nabla\phi(x)=0,\ \forall\ x\in B$, contradicting our assumption.

However, there are closed sets (even compact) that have positive Lebesgue measure and have not an interior point (see: Cantor fat set for example). But beacause $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is locally a $C^1 $graph of a function the conclusion will be true.

I can't figure out how to complete this proof.

Moreover, I know that if $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is bounded (hence compact) then $\phi^{-1}(0)$ has a positive Hausdorff $N-1$ dimensional measure. If the last can be proved then the former is a consequence.

Best wishes and a happy new year!

Comment: But this set is a $C^1$ submanifold of dimension $N-1$. It has Hausdorff dimension $N-1$ and Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that. I want to know what kind of results uses the proof. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a reference. It follows easily from the following exercise: Let $m<n$. $U\subset\Bbb R^m$ be open and let $f\colon U\to\Bbb R^n$ be $C^1$. Then if $X\subset U$ is any compact set, $f(X)$ has *volume* $0$ in $\Bbb R^n$. This is a much stronger statement than saying it has Lebesgue measure $0$. A set has volume $0$ if, given any $\epsilon>0$, it can be covered by finitely many rectangles the sum of whose volumes is $<\epsilon$.